# Second order reaction half life equation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

For the reaction: 
$$2A\to p$$
The rate, $v$ may be given as:
$$v=-\frac12\frac{d[A]}{dt}=k[A]^2$$
Correct?

Integrating this gives:
$$-\frac12\int_{[A]_0}^{[A]}\frac{d[A]}{[A]^2}=k\int_0^tdt$$
$$\frac1{2[A]}-\frac1{2[A]_0}=kt$$
Rearranging...
$$\frac1{[A]}=\frac1{[A]_0}+2kt$$
Now substituting $t=t_{1/2}$ and $[A]=\frac{[A]_0}2$...
$$\frac2{[A]_0}=\frac1{[A]_0}+2kt_{1/2}$$
Minus $1/[A]_0$ from each side...
$$\frac1{[A]_0}=2kt_{1/2}$$
This then gives:
$$t_{1/2}=\frac1{2k[A]_0}$$

However, I have seen in textbooks that this should be written:

$$t_{1/2}=\frac1{k[A]_0}$$

Have I gone wrong somewhere? If so where?

I need to know which equation is correct because when figuring out the rate constant, would the gradient be equal to $\frac{1}{2k}$ or $\frac{1}{k}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you did isn't wrong, but instead of:

$$v=-\frac12\frac{d[A]}{dt}=k[A]^2$$

some write:

$$v=-\frac{d[A]}{dt}=k[A]^2$$

which is also true.

Twice a constant is still as constant (a different constant of course).

See http://www.chem.arizona.edu/~salzmanr/480a/480ants/int2ord/int2ord.html

Comment: So if I wanted the rate constant of the reaction from the gradient of the graph (explained at the bottom of my question) which equation should I use?

Comment: I don't understand that part of the question.  Explain more exactly what you are plotting. Product concentration vs. time? Reactant concentration versus time?

Comment: $t_{1/2}$ against $1/[A]_0$

Comment: both ways would be equally correct, you just have to explain how you are defining the rate constant.

Comment: How can it be correct to get two different rate constants for one reaction?

Comment: Because you can define the rate constant to mean what you wrote (your differential equation) or what the reference wrote.

Comment: Thanks. Please may you take a look at this: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24468/predicting-rate-equations-from-data

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a mathematical answer, but shouldn't the integration produce

1/[A] - 1/[A]0 = kt

which means you don't have your 2kt being taken through your working, and gives you the same as the textbooks' answer(s)?

Comment: I have a factor of minus one half outside the integral from the rate equation

Comment: Where did your -1/2 actually come from?

Comment: Stoichiometry of the reaction

Comment: Ah, DavePhD beat me to it, but basically your value is fixed anyway so half of it is the same thing so it's not 2kt.